# offset operator in assembly language

Tags: assembly

I am a bit confuse. i am not able to find the exact purpose of offset operator in assembly language as i am new to this language. According to the theory OFFSET operator returns the distance of a label from the beginning of the data segment in bytes corresponding the relative modes (Real/Protected). but when i run the following code

```
.data
bVal BYTE ?
wVal WORD ?
dVal DWORD ?
dVal2 DWORD ?
dValArray DWORD 5 DUP(?)
.code
mov esi,OFFSET bVal      ; ESI = 00404000
call DumpRegs

mov esi,OFFSET wVal      ; ESI = 00404001
call DumpRegs

mov esi,OFFSET dVal         ; ESI = 00404003
call DumpRegs

mov esi,OFFSET dVal2         ; ESI = 00404007
call DumpRegs

mov esi,OFFSET dValArray     ; ESI = 0040400B
call DumpRegs
```

i got the output that is given in the comments
what this output mean?
Is this the starting address of the label or the displacement between the starting and final address or anything else that i dont know. I will be thankful if anyone help me in understanding this concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For to show the data addresses:

```
00404000 BYTE ?           ; bVal

00404001 WORD ?           ; wVal
00404002

00404003 DWORD ?          ; dVal
00404004
00404005
00404006

00404007 DWORD ?          ; dVal2
00404008
00404009
0040400A

0040400B DWORD 5 DUP(?)   ; dValArray
0040400C
0040400D
0040400E

0040400F
00404010
00404011
00404012

00404013
00404014
00404015
00404016

00404017
00404018
00404019
0040401A

0040401B
0040401C
0040401D
0040401E
```

(But this arrangement fails totaly for data alignment. Simple solution: Place a second byte after the first one.)

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Windows XP, the data portion of most programs starts at a bit above hex 400000. In this case it appears that your data started at hex 404000. Other versions of Windows may also start the data at the same general location, although Windows 7 and 8 may shift the addresses around a bit as a way to protect programs from simple types of hacks.